# Service Worker Push Notifications with Angular2

Tags: node.js, push-notification, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to piece together the general workflow of giving a user push notifications via the service worker.

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-01?hl=en) Google Developers service worker push notifications tutorial and am currently thinking about how I can implement this sort of thing in a small user based web app for experimentation.

In my mind, the general workflow of an web app supporting push notifications is as follows:

- Client visits app
- Service worker yields a push notification endpoint
- Client sends the endpoint to the server
- Server associates the endpoint with the current user that the endpoint was generated for
- Every time something that your app would say is notification worthy happens, the server grabs the push notification endpoint(s) associated with the user, and hits it to send a push notification to any user devices (possibly with a data payload in Chrome 50+, etc)

Basically I just want to confirm that my general implementation thoughts with this technology are accurate, else get feedback if I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your question is, could you rephrase where is there is confusion / concern? Cheers, Matt

Comment: @GauntFace Sorry! I reworded for clarity. I just want to see if my thoughts on implementing this in an app are accurate, or if there is some simpler way of doing it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are pretty much bang on, there are some specifics that aren't quite right (but this is largely phrasing and may be done to personally taste).

- Client visits app
- Register a Service Worker that you want to use for push messaging
- Use the service worker registration to subscribe the user to push messaging, at which point the user agent will configure an endpoint + additional values for encrypting payloads (If the the user agent supports it).
- Client sends the endpoint to the server
- Server store the the endpoint and data for later use (The server can associate the endpoint with the current user if the server if the web app has user accounts).
- When ever the server wishes to send a notification to a user(s), it grabs the appropriate endpoints and calls them that will wake up the service worker which can then display a notification.

Payload support in coming in Chrome 50+ and at the time of writing payload is support in Firefox, but there are 3 different versions of encryption used for the payloads in 3 different versions of Firefox, so I'd wait for the payload support story to be ironed out a little before using it / relying on it.

Comment: Thanks! Push notification endpoints are associated to a specific service worker correct? One thing I'm confused about is, say a user loads the site on two different devices (generates two different push notification endpoints that the server keeps). Say a site update comes in and a new service worker gets registered (new push notification endpoint generated), Now the user has potentially 4 endpoints associated with them in a database, but only two valid ones...this pattern continues and we've got 50 endpoints/user with only a couple being "up to date"...seems conducive to tons of leaking

Comment: It seems kind of tough to dispose of the right endpoint as a new one gets generated

Comment: Few things on this:
- A user agent may not necessarily issue a new push subscription (Endpoint + other info) on a new service worker
- When  you send a push message using a push subcription, the response will tell you if the subscription is still valid or not - in which case you can clear out old ones
- If it becomes a concern / problem, it is possible to track the previously none subscription using something like indexdb and detect the change and remove the old push subscription with the new